# Manual refund issue

Tags: android, google-play, uninstallation

I have a customer that has requested a refund (as his 15 minute window in play store has expired).  If I give him a refund manually, the play store (as far as I know) will still allow the user to reinstall if uninstalled, and the app will still be on his phone and usable.

I need to know a way around this, something I could code into the app perhaps.  I considered having the app grab the device id and upload it to a remote server, and if its in the DB then the app pops up a window and wont run.  The issue with this is it becomes specific to that device, if the user gets a new phone, or installs on a different device, it will work.

What could I do to make it so that upon giving someone a manual refund, they cant reinstall.  I dont want people being able to get a refund and then just use the app for free.

Ive seen a few other similar questions here about this kind of thing, but they all were closed due to not being programming related.  I want to make sure its known that I am asking a programmatic question, as I hope to implement some sort of check into the app.

Comment: How much is your time worth? Is it really worthwhile to go write up a big software solution to this problem so that the handful of people who you give manual refunds to can't use the app anymore?

Comment: I thought that getting a refund prevents you from reinstalling without repurchasing. Has this changed in the last couple years? I haven't reconfirmed this since then. This is unlikely to be worth your effort...if your app is selling very many copies at all, it is probably already on a load of pirate sites anyway. I doubt there are many people that routinely request refunds for apps they like as a way to exploit the system (if this even is possible).